# Keep app checking webservice even in background (Android)

Tags: android, web-services, service

I saw some examples using Service but I didn't get it right.

I already have in my activity a method using **AsyncTask**, **TimerTask**, Timer and Handler, to do what I need, it is working well.

```
final Handler andlerStatus = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        enviarStatus();
    }
};
taskEnviarStatus = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        Message msg = new Message();
        andlerStatus.sendMessage(msg);
    }
};
timerStatus = new Timer("timerStatus", true);
timerStatus.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskEnviarStatus, esperaInicial, intervalo);
```

The problem is when the app goes to background, it stops sending, by sending I mean "make a webservice call to update a driver status in the server side".

I need even in background the webservice call keep being called.

Comment: This is not an answer, but if your project is a small one you might save yourself some time with http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html. Best.

Comment: I am using GCM for another situation, for this case I just need keep calling the webservice under some conditions, others app on this project check the status updated by that webservice I must call.